# Android convert multipart MultiBodyPart.Part into imageuri or bitmap

Tags: android, android-imageview, multipart

I have a method that returns selected images from the camera or gallery path to MultiBodyPart.Part to be sent to API which is working fine, but at the same time, I need to use this MultiBodyPart.Part and show this in the imageview.
What I am looking for is how can I use MultiBodyPart response to show in my imageview.

Comment: It is unclear what you wanna show in the ImageView. Five pictures?

Comment: If you let the user select some pictures you get some uries. You can use a uri to display a picture in an ImagView. It is unclear to me why you would first put uries in a multipart part and then later extract them from a part.